# HttpResponseMessage Support in Version 2.0 Functions

Tags: azure-functions

I've made heavy utilization of class libraries (ultimately custom Nuget packages hosted in Azure Artifacts) in my v1.0 Azure Functions solution.  I'm now interested in re-using these class libraries with v2.0 Functions to gain Docker support for on-premise applications.  I'm currently running up against an issue where HttpResponseMessage object is not support in v2.0.  This is an issue because the HttpResponseMessage object is generated in the class library itself.  Is there any easy way around this problem (i.e. some sort of shim)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the default is the `HttpRequest` object rather than `HttpResponseMessage` and Return types are `IActionResult/ObjectResult` objects rather than extension methods against `HttpRequestMessage`. I suppose you could use `HttpRequest` to get a return object.

However if you want to return a `HttpResponseMessage`, it's still achievable. Change return type to `HttpResponseMessage` and return a `HttpResponseMessage`.

Below is my test code, maybe you could have a try.

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        var myObj = new { name = "george"};
        var jsonToReturn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj);

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(jsonToReturn, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay... accidentally got consumed with a couple other things.  This worked 100%.  Thank you.